# script is send then Page is not redirect

Tags: php

If click the submit button, then this code should execute, but this is not working.

```
header('Location: http://www.yourtargeturl.com'); //script api
echo '<script>window.open("'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'","_self")</script>';
```

Comment: Please explain "this is not working." Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error? If not, how is the script not behaving as you'd expect?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing PHP and Javascript. The header alone will send the user to the new location in that window.

Note: PHP exists on the server, and is then sent to the browser after being generated/ran, so the javascript you have needs to be echoed to the browser to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your `header('Location: http://www.yourtargeturl.com');` will redirect the page, and make the browser load that page instead.

Everything after that is ignored.  So, your JavaScript `window.open` is never written to the page and ran.